# RPC Failure message on deploying web app on GAE

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, http, gwt

I have the following server class in my GWT web app.

```
 public class WTMServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements WTMService {}
```

I had defined the path :

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("wtmService")
```

It works. Then I added an http server class:

```
public class WTMhttpServiceImpl extends HttpServlet implements WTMhttpService {}
```

and path:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("wtmhttpService")
public interface WTMhttpService 
{
void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response);
}
```

On deploying the app, I get RPC Failure error message(500 POST Internal Server Error). Why am I getting RPC failure?
How do I make both servers work simultaneously?

Comment: 500 Error - read what it says in the logs.

Comment: IN CONSOLE: POST http://URL.com/wtm/wtmService 500 (Internal Server Error)         
wk wtm-0.js:1139
cA wtm-0.js:1135
hA wtm-0.js:914
qN wtm-0.js:1014
KK wtm-0.js:857
OK wtm-0.js:1178
mA wtm-0.js:1157
ok wtm-0.js:1015
Dk wtm-0.js:1177
(anonymous function) wtm-0.js:775
Uf wtm-0.js:568
Yf wtm-0.js:751
(anonymous function)

Comment: All I see on LogCat is : memalloc(1941): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d77b000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:56....That doesn't seem useful..... Sorry, I am very new to this.

Comment: Take a look at the logs in your App Engine admin console at https://appengine.google.com